# How do I set a row as x axis in matplotlib bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, analysis

I want to have the x axis as the years, the y axis as the number of crime and i am looking to do this for each crime.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you need a barplot with years on X-axis and for each year total number of crimes happened? Or I've not understood it correctly?

Comment: @dataLeo yeah thats correct, sorry im new to this and actually have no idea where to start

Comment: Please don't include data, code, error messages as pictures, post them directly here on SO. You should also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Totally agreed with @Mr.T However as a beginner it's good to learn by doing mistakes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included the xticks as years and yaxis as total count of crimes which is present in your first row. Have a look on this and tell me what else you need.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creating a dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Offense':['Total violence', 'Attempted Murder', 'Harrasment'],
                   '01/2018':[23, 21, 2],
                  '05/2018':[140, 80, 60]})
df
#   01/2018 05/2018 Offense
# 0 23      140     Total violence
# 1 21      80      Attempted Murder
# 2 2       60      Harassment

plt.bar(np.arange(2), df.iloc[0,:2])
plt.xticks(np.arange(2), df.columns[:2])
plt.show()
```

[image: plt1]

Comment: Im trying to do this but having problems with 'np.arange(2)' im trying to understand what it does here

Comment: `np.arange(2)` gives you a sequence of 2 numbers [0, 1]. Consider forming a sequence equal to number of bars you need to plot. I suggest you better study basics of `matplotlib` first. Refer here for good understanding of any of the common python packages https://aivic.github.io/tutorial/Python-important-libraries/ Also, you can upvote the answer if it helped you ;)